# rabbitmq - можно ли устанавливать размер очереди?

Tags: rabbitmq

Можно ли в rabbitmq устанавливать размер очереди? Например в 1к сообщений.
И все последующий поступающие сообщения вытесняли первые?

Новое сообщение поступило - самое старое стерлось.

Comment: так? https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html